# execute google appscript from android

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to calling goolge app script from android which access users  google drive and search for csv file.
I am not getting how to authenticate the user and call the script.
can someone share some snippet.

Answer (score 0):

What I can recommend you to do, due to your question is a little generic, is to check the next points:

1) [Enabling script authorization and access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/enable): This will help you to follow the steps to enable the Apps Script API in your [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com).

2) [Executing Functions using the Apps Script API](https://console.cloud.google.com/?angularJsUrl=): Here you will get the info on how to set up everything in your Apps Script API to be able to call it.

Here you will get the info on how to set up everything in your Apps Script API to be able to call it.

3) Use this example code when everything else is set up:

```
/**
 * Call the API to run an Apps Script function that returns a list
 * of folders within the user's root directory on Drive.
 *
 * @return list of String folder names and their IDs
 * @throws IOException
 */
private List<String> getDataFromApi()
        throws IOException, GoogleAuthException {
    // ID of the script to call. Acquire this from the Apps Script editor,
    // under Publish > Deploy as API executable.
    String scriptId = "ENTER_YOUR_SCRIPT_ID_HERE";

    List<String> folderList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Create an execution request object.
    ExecutionRequest request = new ExecutionRequest()
            .setFunction("getFoldersUnderRoot");

    // Make the request.
    Operation op =
            mService.scripts().run(scriptId, request).execute();

    // Print results of request.
    if (op.getError() != null) {
        throw new IOException(getScriptError(op));
    }
    if (op.getResponse() != null &&
            op.getResponse().get("result") != null) {
        // The result provided by the API needs to be cast into
        // the correct type, based upon what types the Apps Script
        // function returns. Here, the function returns an Apps
        // Script Object with String keys and values, so must be
        // cast into a Java Map (folderSet).
        Map<String, String> folderSet =
                (Map<String, String>)(op.getResponse().get("result"));

        for (String id: folderSet.keySet()) {
            folderList.add(
                    String.format("%s (%s)", folderSet.get(id), id));
        }
    }

    return folderList;
}

/**
 * Interpret an error response returned by the API and return a String
 * summary.
 *
 * @param op the Operation returning an error response
 * @return summary of error response, or null if Operation returned no
 *     error
 */
private String getScriptError(Operation op) {
    if (op.getError() == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // Extract the first (and only) set of error details and cast as a Map.
    // The values of this map are the script's 'errorMessage' and
    // 'errorType', and an array of stack trace elements (which also need to
    // be cast as Maps).
    Map<String, Object> detail = op.getError().getDetails().get(0);
    List<Map<String, Object>> stacktrace =
            (List<Map<String, Object>>)detail.get("scriptStackTraceElements");

    java.lang.StringBuilder sb =
            new StringBuilder("\nScript error message: ");
    sb.append(detail.get("errorMessage"));

    if (stacktrace != null) {
        // There may not be a stacktrace if the script didn't start
        // executing.
        sb.append("\nScript error stacktrace:");
        for (Map<String, Object> elem : stacktrace) {
            sb.append("\n  ");
            sb.append(elem.get("function"));
            sb.append(":");
            sb.append(elem.get("lineNumber"));
        }
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    return sb.toString();
}
```